# How to Revoke Dynamics 365 Access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I am using service to service authentication, I get the access token in my daemon service using OAuth 2.0 Client Credential flow using following end point and use it to access Dynamics 365 Web API's
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

Now my daemon service wants to revoke or logout the token how can I achieve this. Please help me on this. What is the token revoke end point?